# WAMP - mysql Error 500 - error while retrieving http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

Hello I just installed WAMP and get the green icon in the bottom of the screen. The local host loads fine and when I click on php info everything works fine.

My problem is when I click on phpmyadmin I get the error code 500 - The website encountered an error while retrieving ...localhost/phpmyadmin/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

I installed Apache before I installed WAMP. Could this be the issue?

My mysql log shows this....

```
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 1626007
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-09-10 10:34:58 5872 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.12-log' socket: '' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: I think you want to look at your PHP log rather than your MySQL log.

Comment: Sarah - the PHP seems to be working fine, but it is MySQLadmin that won't start.  I checked the PHP log and there is no file created yet.

Comment: You are using PHPMyAdmin, not MySQLadmin. If you get a 500 error on a PHP page (phpmyadmin is written in PHP), you have a PHP error. Are you sure you are looking in the right place for your PHP error log, and that error logging is turned on?

Comment: Sarah Kemp is right, but you may also have some hints in your webserver error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled then reinstalled to get this working.